# HTTP post request with OAuth1 through UrlFetchApp in Google App script

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have a problem signing an HTTP post request with the UrlFetchApp in Google App scripts. I only need to sign the request with my consumerKey, I do not need complete authorization with callback and everything. How would I be able to sign the request using OAuth encoding? Do I simply add the OAuth as parameters or as headers? I am very new to this and would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Oauth 1 is now deprecated: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref?hl=en.
What API are you trying to use?

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I am not trying to access Google APIs. I am trying to access a 3rd party API with 2 legged OAuth. Can't find a way to generate signature with URL Fetch App...

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the code you are using and the http request you need to use for the authentication (headers, json, etc.)

Comment: Hey @Gerardo, see my answer below. Google just implemented 2-legged OAuth :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Update on the situation: Google just added 2-legged support to their OAuth1 library. See https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1.

If you are using Google App Script and that library, update it to version 11.

I simply changed the access token in the example to empty string. Now everything works just fine.

Thanks!